# Where are Angular 2 Material Design styles in node_modules?

Tags: angular, material-design, node-modules

I'm trying to understand what's happening in @angular/material library that you install via npm. The only style file I see is `_theming.scss`, which mostly styles colors, depending on chosen theme. What about paddings, margins and other styles, where does it get them from? What is material.umd.js.map file, which apparently imports modules, via styleUrls, but how?
I'll be very grateful for an answer!

Comment: its all there, the individual components have their own themes which are imported into _theming.scss and configurated there. You should check the source code at github for more information

Comment: But the structure of what's on github repository if very different from what's in node_modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so what is happening it's that all the styles are being applied through components in bundled js file in `styles` as strings. And then added to the head of document.